# How is CPU Time in seconds calculated?

Tags: azure, cpu-usage

on my windows azure dashboard, I see cpu time calculated in seconds for a given period. How is that calculated?

Answer (score 0):

This is the amount of time spent processing the requests for your web site.

For example in shared tier, if you scale your app it will change the number of processing threads that are servicing your web site.